# Makefile command gives me missing separator. Stop. error

Tags: macos, makefile, recipe

I am trying to compile the following code using the `Make` command Terminal in OSX (MacOS).It is giving me `*** missing separator.  Stop.**` error.

Code :

```
`XBUILD=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
 PROJECT_ROOT=./InfColorPicker
 PROJECT=$(PROJECT_ROOT)/InfColorPicker.xcodeproj
 TARGET=InfColorPicker
 all: libInfColorPickerSDK.a
 libInfColorPicker-i386.a:
$(XBUILD) -project $(PROJECT) -target $(TARGET) -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release clean build
-mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphonesimulator/lib$(TARGET).a $@
libInfColorPicker-armv7.a:
$(XBUILD) -project $(PROJECT) -target $(TARGET) -sdk iphoneos -arch armv7 -configuration Release clean build
-mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphoneos/lib$(TARGET).a $@
libInfColorPickerSDK.a: libInfColorPicker-i386.a libInfColorPicker-armv7.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -create -output $@ $^
```

clean:
 -rm -f .a .dll`

I have tried giving `TABS` on every line. It doesn't work. Please help

Comment: Formatting in a makefile is important. Each recipe line (the body of a rule, the part that is shell/etc. commands) needs to have a leading tab. All other lines do not. Try formatting your makefile again (and trying to keep it formatted sanely in your post here) and see if you can't get the problem to go away.

Comment: Seems that this makefile is generated from a 3rd application, not directly from the user. If so, you should ask to their folks.

Comment: @Joel I tried using osx textedit and windows notepad editors

Comment: @EtanReisner can u please identify on which lines I should put a leading tab.. I am a newbie.
Thanks